# Does Tapatio red sauce equate to Frank's hot pepper sauce?

Tags: substitutions

Does Tapatio red sauce equate to Frank's RedHot Original Cayenne Pepper Sauce?

Comment: Hey, we need some additional clarity to answer your question.  What do you mean by "equate to"?  In what way?

Answer (score 2):

I would say they are quite different. Tapatio is spicier, and thicker. Frank's Red Hot is thinner, has a more vinegary flavor, and is less spicy.